# как сделать запрос на сторонний домен, используя node js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, request

задачи состоит в том, чтобы сделать ajax запрос на сторонний домен.
возможно это сделать используя модуль request? можно увидеть конкретный пример, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример кода запроса.
Но для этого нужно подключить пакет `cors`.

> $ npm install cors

Вот [ссылка](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) для подробностей подключения пакета.

```js
var request = require('request');
var url = "https://" + username + ":" + password + "@/api/systems";
var option = {
    url: url,
    auth: {
        user: username,
        password: password
    }
};
request(option,
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    }
);
```

Comment: Cors ставится на сервере чтобы упростить настройку заголовков для браузеров. В случае с нодовским клиентом он не нужен